# jQuery Submit Form With Unique Input ID's

Tags: php, jquery, foreach, submit

I have a foreach loop that outputs a form with content for each array entry as per bellow.

```
$cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" id="quantity" />
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" id="adjustBtn" hidden="true" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form></td>';
```

As you can see the submit button has a unique assigned name for depending on the item.

In my jquery file i have the bellow.

```
$('#quantity').change(function(){
$("[name^=adjustBtn]").closest("form").submit();
```

});

This works on the first form on the page but any additional form does not auto submit on change, i believe the name^=adjustBtn entry is grabbing all of the different buttons but im just not sure how to tell it which one to submit etc.

Comment: IDs are unique to the page, you can't have more than one element with the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to need

```
$('[name="quantity"]').change(function(){
   $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Your id doesn't seem needed. And beware that you can't have more than one element with a given id (problem with "quantity" and "adjustBtn" in your code).

Comment: Thanks i have now changed the unique part of the name to be the same for the ID's and updated as per your example and works great. Thanks.